# Linux ppp0 and default route and how to reach public internet

Tags: raspberry-pi, internet, modem, ppp, wvdial

my project needs mobile internet. I am trying to achieve this by using a LTE stick modem with a M2M sim (public IP, no NAT)

This works well on ubuntu (5.3.0-29-generic), but I cannot get it working on Raspbian Buster (4.19.97+)

```
Feb 11 22:31:48 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reloading.
Feb 11 22:31:51 raspberrypi systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Current command vanished from the unit file, execution of the command list won't be resumed.
Feb 11 22:31:51 raspberrypi systemd[1]: serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service: Current command vanished from the unit file, execution of the command list won't be resumed.
Feb 11 22:32:00 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reloading.
Feb 11 22:32:41 raspberrypi pppd[699]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
Feb 11 22:32:41 raspberrypi pppd[699]: Using interface ppp0
Feb 11 22:32:41 raspberrypi pppd[699]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB1
Feb 11 22:32:41 raspberrypi NetworkManager[288]: <info>  [1581460361.7138] manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
Feb 11 22:32:42 raspberrypi pppd[699]: CHAP authentication succeeded: Welcome!!
Feb 11 22:32:42 raspberrypi pppd[699]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Feb 11 22:32:42 raspberrypi pppd[699]: Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
Feb 11 22:32:42 raspberrypi pppd[699]: not replacing default route to eth0 [192.168.0.1]
Feb 11 22:32:42 raspberrypi pppd[699]: local  IP address 10.217.44.214
Feb 11 22:32:42 raspberrypi pppd[699]: remote IP address 10.64.64.64
Feb 11 22:32:42 raspberrypi pppd[699]: primary   DNS address 109.249.185.224
Feb 11 22:32:42 raspberrypi pppd[699]: secondary DNS address 109.249.186.32
Feb 11 22:32:42 raspberrypi NetworkManager[288]: <info>  [1581460362.2378] device (ppp0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Feb 11 22:32:42 raspberrypi NetworkManager[288]: <info>  [1581460362.3090] device (ppp0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Feb 11 22:35:30 raspberrypi pppd[699]: Terminating on signal 15
Feb 11 22:35:30 raspberrypi pppd[699]: Connect time 2.8 minutes.
Feb 11 22:35:30 raspberrypi pppd[699]: Sent 0 bytes, received 0 bytes.
Feb 11 22:35:30 raspberrypi NetworkManager[288]: <info>  [1581460530.4393] device (ppp0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Feb 11 22:35:30 raspberrypi pppd[699]: Connection terminated.
```

For this, I tried using wvdial with these settings

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Auto DNS = yes
Init1 = ATZ+CFUN=1
Init2 = ATH
Init3 = ATE1
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","EEM2M"
Stupid mode = 1
Baud = 9600
Dial Command = ATD
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB1
ISDN = 0
Phone = *99#
Password = bt
Username = bt
```

NetworkManager.conf has this content

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

ppp/resolv.conf has this content

```
nameserver 109.249.185.224
nameserver 109.249.186.32
```

I think this was set by the setup (see log above)

Last but not least, this shows when I do ifconfig -a after wvdial is running. 
Note that the 6 packets in ppp0 are internal pings to 10.217.44.214

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.12  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::b435:fc5d:b267:a226  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:e0:92:00:15:f3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 299  bytes 30739 (30.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 269  bytes 36598 (35.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4  bytes 156 (156.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 156 (156.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.217.44.214  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.64.64.64
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 6  bytes 66 (66.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7  bytes 129 (129.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wwan0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:1e:10:1f:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Edit 1:
When running wvdial as root, I get this:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ+CFUN=1
OK
--> Sending: ATH
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","EEM2M"
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATD*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
CONNECT 150000000
--> Carrier detected.  Starting PPP immediately.
--> Starting pppd at Tue Feb 11 23:01:49 2020
--> Pid of pppd: 1281
--> Using interface ppp0
--> pppd: X?C[01]X?C[01]
--> pppd: X?C[01]X?C[01]
--> pppd: X?C[01]X?C[01]
--> pppd: X?C[01]X?C[01]
--> pppd: X?C[01]X?C[01]
--> pppd: X?C[01]X?C[01]
--> local  IP address 10.217.44.214
--> pppd: X?C[01]X?C[01]
--> remote IP address 10.64.64.64
--> pppd: X?C[01]X?C[01]
--> primary   DNS address 109.249.185.224
--> pppd: X?C[01]X?C[01]
--> secondary DNS address 109.249.186.32
--> pppd: X?C[01]X?C[01]
```

I also noticed that when wvdial is running, the NetworkManager will load the correct DNS in /etc/resolv.conf, changing

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 194.168.4.100
nameserver 194.168.8.100
```

to

```
nameserver 109.249.185.224
nameserver 109.249.186.32
# Generated by NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facing a similar issue,

```
sudo route add default ppp0
```

worked for me.

If you need the process automated, you can create a script in /etc/ppp/ip-up.d, it will be executed when the connection is set.

Comment: Try adding `defaultroute-metric <some_number>` to your pppd config. Look in the manpage for details. In any case, notice that you can have *multiple* default routes, provided that they have different metrics. On Linux, `ip route add` is a better tool than `route add`.

Comment: As shown by the OP's pppd log ("not replacing default route to eth0"), pppd will not trash an existing default route. Nor is doing it a good idea -- NetworkManager and similar will install multiple default routes instead, with different metrics (preferring wired to wifi, wifi to mobile, etc)